# How to log all print statements

Tags: python, stdout

My program is quite big and I want all its print statements to be logged so as a result I implemented

```
F = open('testy.txt','w')
sys.stdout = F

if app.button_press() == True and app.return_data():
    data = app.return_data()
    main(data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7],data[8])

F.close()
```

This is what I used to do with small programs with a few print statements but this program has few hundred of them I guess and as I run my program it freezes I think it has a lot of print statements and a memory overflow occurs therefore How could I log all my print statements to a .txt file without affecting the functionality of it?

Comment: Have you tried with flushing with sys.stdout.flush() ?

Comment: You should really not be doing this. Set up logging and configure it to log to stdout if you want to see it, and a file if you want to log to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using print statements for logging, nor should you be redirecting standard out (or any other standard stream) in production code.  Rather, you should be using the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module to write messages, and setting up whatever handlers, probably a [file handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) or [rotating file handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) in your case, that you need to record your log messages to the right place.

If you already have too much existing code printing log messages to refactor in one sitting, I'd suggest implementing `logging`, using it for all logging going forward, setting up a file-like object that shunts standard out to `logging` to capture existing log messages, then refactoring out all your print-based logging over time.

Comment: Can you provide an example because I've never used the logging module